# Difference between html rendered when client validation is true in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I'm creating a brand new MVC3 site. 
Client side validation enabled on the web.config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Scenario #1: Output HTML generated after a failed (client side) validation:

```
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="UserName" class="field-validation-error">
    <span htmlfor="UserName" generated="true" class="">Please enter an email address</span>
</span>
```

Note the nested span tag where the innermost tag has a class=""

Scenario #2: Custom Server-side validation. With the same web.config configuration, I added a validation on the server to check for a custom business rule. The validation fails, I add the error to the ModelState.

The HTML generated looks like this:

```
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="UserName" class="field-validation-error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
```

Note that just one span tag was generated, NOT a nested tag.

This behavior is making it a pain to deal with my CSS as I can't just style the .field-validation-error class as there are 2 different end results on my generated HTML.

IN SUMMARY: Client side validation generates just 1 span tag, server side validation generates 2 span tags.

QUESTION: Is this the indented behavior of the framework or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The "IN SUMMARY" part is actually inverted, client side validation generates 2 span tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the indented behavior of the framework or am I doing something wrong?

You are not doing anything wrong. It's just how the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script works. So you may call this a missing feature, discrepancy, PITA, whatever but that's how they did it out of the box.

This being said the [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) is extensible and we can tweak it as we like:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    // customize the way errors are shown
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        if (errorList.length < 1) {
            // because we have customized the way errors are shown
            // we need to clean them up if there aren't any
            $('.field-validation-error', this.currentForm).hide().attr('class', 'field-validation-valid');
            $('.input-validation-error', this.currentForm).removeClass('input-validation-error');
            return;
        }
        $.each(errorList, function (index, error) {
            // simply toggle the necessary classes to the corresponding span
            // to make client validation generate the same markup as server
            // side validation
            var element = $(error.element);
            element.attr('class', 'input-validation-error');
            element.next('span').show().text(error.message).attr('class', 'field-validation-error');
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Darin Where would you put the script above, should it be placed in > jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and if so, where? thanks in advance

Comment: @Darin, the script works perfectly, but if I have multiple client-side validation errors, it seems to clear them all as soon as I enter a valid value in the first field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always use nested spans for your validation messages after server validation failure (for styling reasons), you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.field-validation-error').each(function(){
        $(this).html($('<span>').text($(this).text()));
    });
});
```