# MVC Field Validator for an Email Address is generating an extra span tag

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC3 application that was has an extremely poor master CSS file that I can't edit without a significant amount of redevelopment work (which is coming... but I can't do this right now).  I have the following code block:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.ValidationMessage("")
```

There's a fair amount of structure around these three lines.

The problem that I have is that this generates the following HTML when it renders the first two error messages:

```
<div class="field-validation-adddiscount">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Email">
    <span class="" for="Email" generated="true">
        The Email Address field is not a valid e-mail address.
    </span>
</span>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Password"></span>
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="">
  The email address or password provided is incorrect. Please try again.
</span>
```

Why is this generating two span classes for the Email address validation message (and can I get rid of it or inject a class into the span?  I've attempted to set the @id in the ValidationMessage, but it assigns this to the parent span and the sub-span still causes the css to go mental (I have to work with a really poor css master file - one thing that's on the "i wish the client would pay for the time to rewrite it" list)

I know it's related to jquery unobtrusive validation as I've attempted to implement the fix from this post: [Difference between html rendered when client validation is true in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979862/difference-between-html-rendered-when-client-validation-is-true-in-mvc3)  however this just seems to do weird things with the validation including preventing the email validation message from appearing at all.

Comment: It sounds like to get this to output the html you'd like you would have to write custom a `ValidationMessageFor` HtmlHelper to replace the current one -- then you can output any html you want. You'll also have to figure out how jquery unobtrusive validation works under the hood. It seems to me that clearing or resetting the master css for this section would be easier. I'd expect the existing css rules would give you trouble in any case.

Comment: It would be easier to turn off inheritance for the span tags in this case, however I can see why the standards people don't want to introduce spaghetti css.  It's frustrating because the master css is utter garbage but it can't be re-written just yet. I'll look into writing a custom htmlhelper - something I'd not considered yet.  Short term I might just throw the validations into a floating div and absolutely position it - ugly hack but should get me out of the poo.

Comment: Maybe you would like the `Html.ValidationSummary()` helper it renders all your errors in a bulleted list

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Daniele - that rendered a little better, but the other validations on the form (ones managed by the jQuery unobtrusive script) didn't appear at all.